# How to extend JQuery 3 selector in TypeScript

Tags: jquery, typescript

After upgrading JQuery from 2 to 3, the latest TypeScript definition no longer contains:

```
expr: any;
```

Our code base extends the JQuery selector to provide a case insensitive selector:

```
    $.extend($.expr[":"], {
        containsCaseInsensitive: (elem: any, i: number, match: any, array: any) =>
            (elem.textContent || elem.innerText || "").toLowerCase().indexOf((match[3] || "").toLowerCase()) >= 0
    });
```

With the latest TS definition, this no longer transpiles.  Is there a way to provide the same functionality in JQuery 3 without manually updating the TS definition for JQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code posted now works as of `@types/jquery@3.3.12` (fixed by [DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped#29503](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/29503)).

---

For older versions, you would've had to add the following declaration to your project.

```js
interface JQueryStatic {
    expr: any;
}
```

This declaration would merge with the declaration of `JQueryStatic` from `@types/jquery` and make `expr` available.